# Equivalent condition for Differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Is it possible to prove that

$f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable at $c \in (a,b)$

iff

there exists a real number $f'(c)$ such that for all $x \in (a,b)$, $f(x) = f(c) + f'(c)(x-c) + e(x)$
for some function $e:(a,b) \to\mathbb R$ s.t $e(x)\to 0$ as $x\to c$

without assuming that differentiability at $c$ implies continuity at $c$?

(sorry for the lack of LaTeX, i'm in a rush)

Comment: the "if" is easy. i need the "only if"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's wrong. Your $e(x)$ should be replaced with $(x-c)e(x)$, making it a $o(x-c)$, using Landau notation.

Modulo this correction, the equivalence holds.

Proof of the *only if* : 
$$f(x) = f(x) + (x-c) \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = f(c) +(x-c)f'(c) - (x-c)[\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - f'(c)]$$

And the thing between brackets is actually a $e(x)$

Comment: are you sure? i think i proved this given diff => cts :

Comment: suppose differentiabily.
let e(x) = f(x) - f(c) - f'(c)(x-c).

given that f is cts this gives that e -> 0 as x -> c

.Conversely suppose the condition.
now we can show that the limit of (f(x)-f(c))/(x-c) is f'(c)

Comment: The *conversely* is false there. The limit of $e(x)/(x-c)$ has no reason to be 0.

Comment: thanks for clearing this up, i was being silly

Comment: No problem. You can see this as a particular case of the Taylor formula, if you want to look it up.

Comment: yeah i should have realized. this was given to us as a smoother way of proving the chain rule, differentiability of the inverse, and diff => cts .

thanks again.